# How to properly use ENV variables in Nginx config?

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, lua, env

I want to pass the `RAILS_ENV` env variable to nginx and use it to set the value for the `rails_env` directive.

I can read the value of the variable from the environment with LUA module:

```
location @app {
    set_by_lua $env_rails_env 'return os.getenv("RAILS_ENV")';
    return 200 'rails env is: ${env_rails_env}';
}
```

When I `curl` it, I get the correct answer:

```
[jsosic@workstation ~]$ curl http://localhost:3005/
rails env is: development
```

But, if I want to use it as a value for nginx directive:

```
location @app {
    set_by_lua $env_rails_env 'return os.getenv("RAILS_ENV")';
    rails_env         $env_rails_env;
    limit_req         zone=one burst=100;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

I get the following log:

```
Message from application: '${env_rails_env}' database is not configured.
Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"]
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation it seems that `passenger_app_env` (which `rails_env` is aliased to) is not accepting the variable and instead treating it as a literal.

https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker/issues/28

So, instead of `$env_rails_env` expanding to the content of the `$RAILS_ENV` read by lua, it's treated as a string `$env_rails_env`. That's why the log line is reporting `database not configured`.

Also, per nginx Q & A, variables shouldn't be used in configuration files:

> "[Variables] are rather costly compared to plain static configuration.
>   [A] macro expansion and "include" directives should be used [with]
>   e.g. sed + make or any other common template mechanism."
>   http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html

What I ended up is using `envsubst(1)`.